# How do I remove case-sensitivity from my combo box's autocomplete (Access form)

Tags: ms-access, autocomplete, combobox, case-sensitive

I've built a data entry form in access. One of the fields [Operator] comes from a combo-box of operator names, such as "Jane Doe". The people who enter the data typically keep caps lock on for other elements of the form, and so when they get to the [Operator] field as they start typing, the autocomplete will do the following:

```
User types: J
Autocomplete: Jane Doe

User types: JA
Autocomplete: Jane Doe

User types: JAN
Autocomplete: JaNne Doe
```

So, if there are 2 operators with similar first names and the user needs to type more than 2 letters of the name, autocomplete gets caught up on the case-sensitivity and burdens the user.

The simplest solution I've found so far is to convert all the names to all caps, but is there a way to make autocomplete work regardless of case?

Comment: Wow, that's some crazy behavior.  I had to try that myself before I believed you.  Great example allowing others to reliably reproduce the problem.  +1

Comment: Just to muddy the waters a bit (and maybe this will make sense to someone else), but if I type in: `JaNE DOE` then Autocomplete works correctly.  Also, if I type in: `jANE DOE` then Autocomplete works correctly.  It seems to only be a problem if the first two letters are both Capitalized and the entry in the combo box is not all caps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the Allow Autocorrect option to No.

What is happening is that the Autocorrect for two initial capitals is cutting in at `A` and the combo is losing the text selection, so when N is typed, it is inserted, not over-typed.

Comment: What a bizarre place to hide this functionality, but indeed that works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: +1: @Remou, how on earth do you retain all of this obscure Access trivia?